# How to call a CJuidialog through action in Yii

Tags: javascript, yii, modal-dialog

I am doing a project where I needed my CJuidialog called through the actionCreate. Is there a way of doing that? I only want to have a simple dialog which contains some text and button submit and cancel if it satisfies my condition. here is what i have started.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new EmpSched;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['EmpSched']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EmpSched'];
        if($model->default==1){

            Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('my_script', 'alert("Hi     there!");', CClientScript::POS_READY);

        }else{
            ($model->save());
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_empsched));
        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'emp'=> new CActiveDataProvider('schedule'),
    ));
}
```

here is the output:

![enter image description here][1]

The problem im encountering is that I cant call the CJuidialog in my condition in actionCreate. **I want to do If it satisfies my condition display Dialog, if not just save.**

Answer (score 0):

In yii there is a confirm key in htmlOptions:

```
echo CHtml::button('Delete', array('submit' =>Yii::app()->createUrl("/post/delete", array("id" => $model->id)), 'confirm'=>'Are you sure?', 'name'=>'delte'));
```